# Inline Visualforce page in Record Details Page - How to get Title Name in a single line?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing a code for "Use an inline Visualforce page in Record Details Page?". In this example,

**InLineController**

```
public class InLineController {
    public Contact cont {set; get; }
    public Id accRecId;
    public Account accRec {set; get; }

    public InLineController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null){
            Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            accRecId = [select id,accountid from contact where id = :id].accountid;
            if(accRecId != null){
                accRec = [select id,name,accountnumber,annualrevenue from account where id =:accRecId];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**InLineControllerVFPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="InLineController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Inline Visualforce page">
            <b>Account Name : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.name}" /> <br/>
            <b>Account Number : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.accountNumber}" /> <br/>
            <b>Annual Revenue : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.annualrevenue}"/><br/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**The only problem which I face is that I want "My Inline Visualforce page" in a single line. How we can get that ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Admano - As per suggestion, we can used it in the `<apex:form style="white-space: nowrap;">` like below. It works fine.

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" extensions="InLineController">
    <apex:form style="white-space: nowrap;">
       <apex:pageBlock title="My Inline Visualforce page">
        <b>Account Name : </b> <apex:outputField value="{!accRec.name}"/><br/>
        <b>Account Number: </b> <apex:outputField value="{!accRec.accountnumber}"/><br/>
         <b>Annual Revenue : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.annualrevenue}"/>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm Adamo :D Remember that :D

Comment: Thanx, Corrected your name.

Comment: Great, simple solution works !

Comment: No problem :D I joked

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`<apex:sectionHeader title="" subTitle=""/>`

instead of

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Inline Visualforce page">
```

Your example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="InLineController">
    <apex:form>
      <apex:sectionHeader title="My Inline Visualforce page" subTitle=""/>`
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <b>Account Name : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.name}" /> <br/>
            <b>Account Number : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.accountNumber}" /> <br/>
            <b>Annual Revenue : </b><apex:outputField value="{!accRec.annualrevenue}"/><br/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

--edit

Did you try add css style:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bPageBlock .pbBody { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
```

Comment: No, I dont want to use it as SectionHeader, I want to use it as pageBlock only.

Comment: Understood. I add a new proposition

Comment: Unsupported attribute style in `<apex:pageBlock> in InLineControllerVFPage at line 3 column 88,` we cant use style.

Comment: Please check my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

The page section needs to be one column edit the page layout to set it as 1 column.

Comment: Great, simple solution works !